# Testing optional arguments in PHP

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, default-value, optional-parameters

I have a few "setter" methods across classes, and for convenience I've added an optional parameter `$previous`, which takes an argument by reference and populates it with the existing value before replacing it with the new one. For example:

```
public function set_value($key, $value, &$previous = null)
{
    $previous = $this->get_value($key);
    $this->_values[$key] = $value;
    return $this;
}
```

This works fine; however in some circumstances, the corresponding "getter" method is a bit process intensive, and running it unconditionally is a waste. I figured I could test:

```
if(null !== $previous)
{
    $previous = $this->get_value($key);
}
```

This doesn't work though, as often the variable passed as the argument for `$previous` hasn't been previously defined in it's scope, and defaults to null anyway. The only solution I've hacked out is:

```
public function set_value($key, $value, &$previous = null)
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    if(isset($args[2])
    {
        $previous = $this->get_value($key);
    }
    $this->_values[$key] = $value;
    return $this;
}
```

Or, to one-line it:

```
if(array_key_exists(2, func_get_args()))
{
    // ...
}
```

I don't like the method body being reliant on the argument indices (*when it seems it should be unnecessary*) Is there a cleaner way to achieve what I'm after here?

---

I've tried:

```
if(isset($previous)){}

if(!empty($previous)){}

if(null !== $previous){}
```

Neither work.

Possible solutions thus far:

```
if(func_num_args() == $num_params){}

if(array_key_exists($param_index, func_get_args())){}

// 5.4
if(isset(func_get_args()[$param_index])){}

// 5.4
if(func_num_args() == (new \ReflectionMethod(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__))
    ->getNumberOfParameters()){}
```

---

@DaveRandom -- So, something in the area of:

```
define('_NOPARAM', '_NOPARAM' . hash('sha4096', microtime()));

function foo($bar = _NOPARAM)
{
    // ...
}
```

---

@hoppa -- Use case:

```
$obj->set_something('some_key', $some_value, $previous) // set
    ->do_something_that_uses_some_key()
    ->set_something('some_key', $previous) // and reset
    ->do_something_that_uses_some_key()
    -> ...
```

Instead of:

```
$previous = $obj->get_something('some_key'); // get
$obj->set_something('some_key', $some_value) // set
    ->do_something_that_uses_some_key();
    ->set_something($previous) // and reset
    ->do_something_that_uses_some_key();
    -> ...
```

Comment: Couldn't you define the default value for `$previous` as `FALSE` (or some value of the "wrong" type) - then you know that it is `null` it was passed, but it it is `FALSE` (or whatever) it wasn't. This method has holes in it as well (the user might pass your default value) but I think it would be a decent approach - especially if you make the default value a long random string that is highly unlikely to be in the variable that was passed.

Comment: @DaveRandom -- The previous value could be a boolean `false` in some circumstances. I chose `null` for it's semantic intent, "absence of value".

Comment: See edited comment about long random string - I admit it's not a beautiful or flawless approach, but it is a works 99.99999% approach...

Comment: @DaveRandom -- I suppose I could define some arbitrary string as the default, but that (*much akin to the argument of `md5`*) still holds possibility of collisions. I figured this would be trivial, and I was merely overlooking something.

Comment: Indeed it does sound trivial, and there may be some method of doing this of which I am also not aware, which is why the comments are not an answer :-D

Comment: What about yet another variable `$fetch_previous` and test explicitly for `$fetch_previous == true`? Too much rework?

Comment: @J0HN -- No, not too much rework (*essentially search/replace*) however, I wouldn't think a check flag would be needed. That was a consideration I've made, but I'm hoping for something a bit more elegant.

Comment: To be honest, it is just bad design. I can imagine this is not what you want to hear, but a function that does two things smells like (and in this case is causing) trouble. I would strongly advice you to just use the getter before you set a new value.

Comment: @hoppa -- I can appreciate that; I know that it violates the command-query separation rule, however it has it's place, for floating values for reuse through chained method calls. In any case, this has become more of an academic issue, as to why something seemingly trivial (*checking whether or not an argument was indeed passed, by checking it's name, not parameter index*) necessitates jumping through hoops (*or checking it's parameter index*) I mean, I've dealt with the idiosyncratic nonsense that is PHP for quite some time, however it always manages to surprise me.

Comment: Have you tried php's magic methods by the way?

Comment: @edem -- I'm not quite sure I follow; are you referring to proxying with `__call()` and checking the passed arguments array? (*I don't think I want to do that*)

Comment: @Bracketworks What you're looking for is a value that cannot be passed in from outside the function - there is no such thing. As a small improvement over what you've already done with `func_get_args`, I'd use `func_num_args` - this way you'll be checking the number of passed arguments, not the argument indices. PS: in your examples, only the `array_key_exists(...)` will work correctly, the `isset()` will have the same problems as checking for `null`.

Comment: @draevor -- That's the problem, I'm not concerned with the value, only whether or not the argument has been supplied. I'll fall back on `func_num_args()` suggestion you've made for now, however I'm interested to see if anyone can concoct something else.

Comment: Yep, but in order to check whether the argument was passed you have 2 options - check the value of the argument against a value (hence my previous comment) or check the number of arguments. Anyway, I've thought some more about the problem and I think checking the number of arguments is the most clean (fast, readable, etc) way. Interesting question in any case :)

Comment: Thanks @draevor -- Well certainly post it up as an answer; I'll let this sit for a bit, but it's starting to seem that it is the fastest, most readable way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

possibly not how you wanted to solve your problem (testing somehow optional arguments), but this is how I would implement it:

```
public function set_value($key, $value)
{
    $this->_values[$key] = $value;
    return $this;
}
public function set_get_value($key, $value, &$previous)
{
    $previous = $this->get_value($key);
    $this->_values[$key] = $value;
    return $this;
}
```

*Use case example:*

```
$obj->set_get_something('some_key', $some_value, $previous) // set AND get
    ->do_something_that_uses_some_key()
    ->set_something('some_key', $previous) // and reset
    ->do_something_that_uses_some_key()
    -> ...
```

**Why use another function?**

This solution has a few advantages:

1. the name is more explicit, less confusion for other coders
2. no hidden side effects
3. solves your problem with (undefined) variables already having a value
4. no overhead of calling `func_num_args`, or some other "meta" function

EDIT: typo in code.

EDIT 2: removed default value of &$previous set_get_value() function (thanks to draevor)

Comment: Good alternative. A small correction - `&$previous` needn't have a default value in the second function, it's meant to be there.

Answer (score 2):

Extracted from the comments / discussion above:

In order to check whether the argument was passed you have 2 options - check the value of the argument against a value (as you've done with null) or check the number of arguments.

If you go with the first option, there's no value that cannot be passed from outside the function, so there will always be a chance for false positives (the same thing that's happening now with null). DaveRandom's example with a random string should be enough for most cases though, but I see it as overkill.

I think the second option is the most clean (fast, readable, etc). As a small improvement over what you've already done with `func_get_args`, I'd use `func_num_args` - this way you'll be checking the number of passed arguments, not the argument indices.

Comment: Thanks @draevor -- Check my edit under "*I've tried/Possible solutions*", the last one (*once 5.4 hits the streets*) would work well for class agnostic re-usability in a trait, given the `$previous` parameter is always last. Like I said before, your answer is certainly the best candidate though, I'll let this sit for a bit, and mark yours if nothing else comes outta the woodwork.